# Some of my prime numbers are coming up as not prime

Tags: java, primes

Im not too sure whats wrong with my code, it seems like most things are coming up prime.

```
public static char isPrime(int x)
        {
            char result = 'r';
            for(int y=2;y<x;y++)
            {
                if(x%y==0)
                result = 't';
                else
                result = 'f';
            }
            return result;
        }
```

Comment: You really should start using boolean instead of dealing with char comparison.

Comment: could you give us an example?

Comment: Assuming `'t'` means composite and `'f'` means prime, you're only returning whether or not `x-1` divides `x` since result is written on each loop iteration.

Comment: If this is homework I suggest talking to your TA, you can likely get a solution here.  But if you want to understand it, and also know what the teacher wants you to learn, then going to your TA will help you the most.

Comment: @jlordo the code is duplicated, but the previous question was only asking about the compiler errors. this question is asking different.  It's a good thing that he's only asking 1 question per question.

Comment: Oops, I missed the fact that `'t'` is supposed to stand for `true` and `'f'` for `false` (figured it might be in another language). As others have suggested, you've got the test backwards. In addition to being stylistically bad, the code as currently written returns `'r'` for `x == 2` (where it should return `'t'`/`true`) and `x <= 1` (where it should return `'f'`/`false` or throw an exception on non-positive numbers if you like)

Answer (score 4):

You are always going to the end of the loop so the result will be for `x-1`.

You need to start with `result = 't'` and break out of the loop for `false` values.

Answer (score 3):

When you just toggle like that, you throw away all previous results.

Assume it is prime until you find a composite number

```
public static char isPrime(int x)
{
    char result = 't';
    for(int y=2;y<x;y++)
    {
        if(x%y==0)
        {
            result = 'f';
            break;
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Lol we ended up with the exact same code.

Answer (score 2):

```
public static char isPrime(int x)
    {
        char result = 't';
        for(int y=2;y<x;y++)
        {
            if(x%y==0) {
                result = 'f';
                break;
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
public static boolean isPrime(int x) {
    for (int y = 2; y*y <= x; y++) {
        if (x % y == 0)
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

What was changed:

- You should use boolean values to indicate that a condition is true or false, instead of the characters `'t'` and `'f'`.
- The biggest problem in your code was that, as soon as you found a divisor for your number (`if (x%y==0)`) you *must* break out of the loop, because at this point we're sure that the number is not prime, so there's no point in continuing
- Only if no divisors were found, we can return `true` at the end, outside of the loop

Comment: eeeewwwwwwwww boolean :-P

Comment: I +1 'ed, but then I noticed the terrible faux pas of `y < x`. Three more keystrokes is all it takes to make this right. :)

Comment: @WillNess you're of course, right. Copy-paste error, fixed it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You should `break` or `return` after you find out that your number is not a prime, simple as that. Additionally it seems that you return `t` when the number is NOT a prime.

Answer (score 1):

Please use boolean and provide an Junit testcase, so we know what you exactly expect.

```
public static boolean isPrime(int x)
        {

            for(int y=2;y<x;y++)
            {
                if(x%y==0)
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your true and false are reversed, if its exactly divisable by something its not prime

Also, you're overwriting all your old data on each run through the loop, as soon as anything is exactly divisible then its not prime, return false at that point

Also, have you considered using the booleans true and false?

Answer (score 0):

You method is not resolving prime numbers. A number is a prime if it can only be divided by one or itself.

If I input 17 into your method, for example, the result will be set to 'f' when y == 16, and that will be the returned result. However, 17 is a prime number.

You should instead try something like

```
for (int i = 2; i < x; i++) {
  if (x % y == 0) return false;
}
return true;
```